# Adding 0's In the middle of a cell?

Tags: excel, formula

I know how to add leading 0's, but I was wondering if it is posible to add them in a middle of a cell to = 12 characters. The first two characthers are always going to be letters. and then nummbers.

Example

```
AB45686 = AB0000045686

DS456 = DS0000000456
```

Comment: is always starting with the third character?

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes!

Comment: @ScottCraner This worked thank you! I will make sure to mark it when I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse the string with LEFT and MID, then use text to add the needed 0s:

```
=LEFT(A1,2) & TEXT(--MID(A1,3,LEN(A1)),"0000000000")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the other way to get the result.[image]